# HTTP File upload boundary choice

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, http-headers, boundary

So I am currently studying HTTP file uploads (in the context of using a `HttpWebRequest` to upload some files to an external API) and generally I see a few dozen dashes being used as the boundary. Browsers seem to usually add a randomly chosen hexadecimal number to the dashes as well.

This seems horribly clunky to say the least (dare I say a flaw in the protocol?). Since my particular usecase involves data that might very well contain the boundary I use (no matter what I pick; the data is a dump of sorts) I need to be 100% certain the file I upload doesn't break things. Randomly picking a number is simply not acceptable to me, even if the chance of an actual collision is 1 in a billion. Retrying with a different randomly picked boundary if the target script detects some error isn't something I am fond of either.

Is the only way for me to avoid this to scan through my entire file (often many megabytes large) to see if my chosen boundary does not exist? I need to perform many different requests with uploads, so in order to avoid the I/O penalty I want to avoid scanning over the entire file.

Or is there some kind of size parameter I can pass so that the boundary becomes little more than a formality?

What am I missing? Changing the remote API is not an option, so encoding in Base64 or adding some kind of escape character aren't possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't personally know of a way faster than scanning your data for the boundary. For the majority of applications, I believe this is how they do it (download the source for Firefox and take a look maybe?).

1. Random boundary created (ideally not likely to occur in data, e.g. --------saDad8g3--------)
2. Data searched for the boundary being contained in it
3. If boundary is found, return to 1.

My guess is that if the boundary is found, the code changes the random boundary created and scans again.

You could probably optimize this by changing step 3 to: If boundary is found, append a byte to the end of the boundary that isn't the next byte in the data and continue searching data.

If you *really* think that your application has such high performance requirements that scanning your upload for your boundary is a problem, I would recommend this alternative:

1. Random boundary created (again, ideally not likely to occur in data)
2. Don't check your data for occurrences (and just presume that a collision chance is VERY low) and do upload.
3. If you get a server error, return to step 1 which will create a new boundary which hopefully isn't ALSO in the data try again.

My guess though is that it is better to simply scan the data before upload than to have to sort out if a 400 error from the server is your upload boundary's fault, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure uniqueness, use a UUID/GUID for the boundary string, as used in the code shown in: https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/

An online GUID generator: https://guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When using all [70 characters](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) for a random alphanumeric boundary and a 1GB of data your chance of collision is not 1 in a billion but more like 1 in 10¹¹⁷. You have more chances of losing your left pinky toe in the next yoctosecond due to a meteor strike. If that doesn't give you confidence than I afraid nothing will :). Please read my answer to a virtually identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48615802/926057).

Answer (score -1):

"What am I missing?"

Common sense ? :P

Here is a way - read in your file to upload, then modify a random byte and voila, you have crafted yourself a boundary that does not recur in the file to upload for sure. But really, it is pointless. Putting in a 10k boundary for instance would dim the probability of a clash to the extent that human kind would be far more probable to vanish until the byte clash occurs.

Comment: I dare say I have the common sense or I'd not be questioning this boundary-mechanic in the first place. ;) Obviously, a filesized boundary is a pretty pointless affair in itself.

Comment: As the OP says, you dont need to worry about this. For eg, you can read your file, generate an MD5 hash and use that as the boundary. Also, see this article http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2010/03/multipart-form-upload-helper.html which shows how to do multipart upload using WebClient. It will take care of most of the details about formatting the upload stream for you.

Comment: @feroze - I don't see what advantage using an MD5 hash as the boundary has... just because it is a hash of the data doesn't mean it doesn't occur in the data (which is the OP's point)

Comment: While I havent done the math, the probability of collision is very low. I think the OP is over thinking this issue.