# How to escape Multipart HTTP boundary

Tags: http, multipart

Let's say I'm sending a multipart request (or response). I need to choose a multipart boundary which does not appear in any of my payloads. However, my payloads are large binary files and I am streaming them to the destination. I want to avoid streaming them twice - once to scan for the boundary and one to stream out.

So my question is: is it possible to escape the boundary if it appears in the payload? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

[Don't Panic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Don't_Panic). Your boundary can be up to [70 characters long](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html). If you go with that maximum and randomly generate it out of characters and numbers you'll have 62⁷⁰ possible combinations for each position in a file. Chance of having the same sequence of bytes in your binary files is so infinitesimal that it shouldn't bother your sleep at all . The probability of collision in a 1GB file is roughly 1-((1-(1/(62^70)))^(10^9)) ~= 3.4*10⁻¹¹⁸. Human brain can't really fathom how small that number is. For comparison the [number of atoms in our universe](https://www.quora.com/How-many-atoms-are-there-in-the-known-universe) is estimated to be ~ 10⁸⁰.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible; you need to either scan, or live with potential failures.